# You have mail in /var/spool/mail/root

Tags: server

```
You have mail in /var/spool/mail/root.
```

Can someone tell me what does this mean?

Comment: Related: [Why does terminal say: “You have mail”?](https://superuser.com/q/25738/84807)

Comment: Have you tried reading it to find out what it says? Usually it is related to cron jobs or some system report.

Comment: yes, I opened the file so many things are there. some line is in reference with the cron jobs I have added :)

Answer (score 11):

A task has run on your machine that had some output, but had nowhere to leave it. So it sent you an email. Because there is no full email system on your machine either, all it could do was to write a message in `/var/spool/mail/root`.

Switch to the root user and see what the mail is about:

```
sudo less /var/spool/mail/root
```

Comment: Or install mailutils: `sudo apt install mailutils` to get the mailx command whare you can read, save and delete mails in /var/mail.

Comment: Is there a way a bash script can detect/be triggered when there is a new mail in `/var/spool/mail/root`?

Comment: @bilogic You could run a script every 5 minutes that does `find /var/spool/mail/root -mmin -5` and notifies you if there is any output. Or you could write a fancy server process which does `inotifywait` on that folder, and starts up at boot time.

Comment: To read the mail sent to root, I used the command: `sudo mail -u root`

Answer (score 3):

Run

```
crontab -e
```

and add output to your cron jobs. If you want to disable emails for just one cron job, you will need to redirect its output to

```
/dev/null by adding > /dev/null 2>&1
```

at the end of the line. For example:

```
* * * * */5 /path/to/command arguments > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: There are often a reason for cron jobs to output, redirecting it to /dev/null makes it impossible to dig into them at a later state. It would be better to use mali/mailx to read them an delete them after that.